# Jfreechart vertical line is blurry

Tags: jfreechart, blurry

I am using JFreechart to generate some plots, and I found the lines in my plot is blurry, but the demo shows that all the lines are thin and without any blurry, I was wondering if there any to generate good quality plot on a panel.
 [image: Comparison]

Comment: I used exactly the same code as the demo used.

Comment: Have you tried chartjs?

Comment: @Nitin not yet... I am developing a java app, this app is used for data processing and visualization, so I am just using java and java lib to write this app. There are a lot of lines on one plot, and I just want to make these line thin and sharp without blurry edge.

Comment: @Nitin thank you, I will look at ds3 js! But I still want to figure it out why they have different appearance...

Comment: Why not use `.png` format instead of `.jpg`?

Comment: @trashgod I didn't generate pictures, the picture that I attached was a screen shot, I don't know why some lines is nice and thin, but some lines are blurry and thick especially when I zoom in. I just want to make all the lines nice and thin on a chart ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With more information, I can't explain the rendering and resampling artifact illustrated in your question. Starting from `MinMaxCategoryPlotDemo1.java` in the [demo](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/samples.html), I added this line to get the `PNG` image shown.

```
ChartUtilities.saveChartAsPNG(new File("temp.png"), jfreechart, 1024, 768);
```

In particular,

- I chose a larger size, as it's generally better to have more pixels than fewer when [resampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_scaling).
- I chose [`PNG`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics), a lossless image format used in the [`MinMaxCategoryRenderer`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/category/MinMaxCategoryRenderer.html) API image.

Click to enlarge:

[image]