# Convert svg chart to pdf and alter chart position

Tags: svg, charts, jfreechart, pdfbox, batik

I want to create a chart with [Object Refinery JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/). After that, I want to create a pdf with [Apache PDFBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org), where I use the chart from JFreeChart. When I save the chart as png or jpg, then the quality of the chart is very bad. So I save the chart as svg and convert it with Apache Batik to pdf. The quality in the pdf is good but I can't alter the position of the chart in the pdf.

How can I alter the position of the chart?
Is there a better solution to generate a chart as svg and put it in a pdf?

Here is my code of how I convert the svg to pdf:

```
    public void convertSVGtoPDF() throws TranscoderException, IOException{
     //Step -1: We read the input SVG document into Transcoder Input
     String svg_URI_input = 
     Paths.get("output_pie_chart.svg").toUri().toURL().toString();
     System.out.println("Path="+svg_URI_input);
     TranscoderInput input_svg_image = new TranscoderInput(svg_URI_input); 

     //Step-2: Define OutputStream to PDF file and attach to TranscoderOutput
     OutputStream pdf_ostream = new FileOutputStream("FinalPDF.pdf");
     TranscoderOutput output_pdf_file = new TranscoderOutput(pdf_ostream);

     // Step-3: Create a PDF Transcoder and define hints
     Transcoder transcoder = new PDFTranscoder();
     transcoder.addTranscodingHint(SVGAbstractTranscoder.KEY_HEIGHT, new 
     Float(800)); transcoder.addTranscodingHint(SVGAbstractTranscoder.KEY_WIDTH, new Float(800));
    transcoder.addTranscodingHint(PrintTranscoder.KEY_MARGIN_TOP,new Float (80));


    // Step-4: Write output to PDF format
    transcoder.transcode(input_svg_image, output_pdf_file);

    // Step 5- close / flush Output Stream
    pdf_ostream.flush();
    pdf_ostream.close();  

    }

}
```

Comment: Some ideas [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38295029/230513).

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-3697 . If you find it useful, please enter some feedback there.