# Dynamic reports blurry font in exported chart

Tags: jasper-reports, jfreechart, dynamic-reports

Exported data to excel in Dynamic reports, and noticed chart texts in labels looks kinda bad.
Is there a way to increase picture size? Or font to look better?
Option `report.addProperty("net.sf.jasperreports.image.dpi", 200);` seem to not have any effect.

[image]

Comment: You've posted a PNG image, but it reminds me of JPG compression artifact; see also this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38295029/230513).

Comment: Ty for comment, but i dont know if how to handle pictures export in Dynamic reports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DynamicReports does not react to `report.addProperty("net.sf.jasperreports.image.dpi", 200);` on main report.
It works only when it is set globally.
To set this property, create a file named jasperreports.properties, put it into the root of the classpath and add the following configuration to the file `et.sf.jasperreports.image.dpi=200`